# Error on checking balance via USSD

Tags: putty, at-command, modem, 3g, ussd

I've been trying to check my balance from by 3g modem via AT commands and seem to be stuck.

The device infomation is as follows:

Manufacturer: QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
Model: M6281
Revision: SSD_M6281A-0.0.1   1  [Oct 02 2008 07:00:00]

The modem has USSD capability (advertised and also present in the factory installed dashboard).

I am connecting via putty to COM4 serial port which is my modems application port. All AT commands are working fine but I am getting an error on issuing the following via putty:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*111#",15
```

This returns a simple "ERROR". *111# is my carrier's balance check code. I suspect that there is a formatting error somewhere but I can't figure out where.

Note: If I issue a blank ussd command:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"",15
```

then I get an OK (although I later get a response +CME ERROR: retry operation) ... If I write anything within the quotation marks however, it returns an "ERROR".

Comment: Have you verified that your modem is registered to a mobile network? Via AT+CREG?

Comment: @aldrimic AT+CREG?

+CREG: 0,1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the way to fix this. Apparently there was a problem in the encoding. Here is what I did:

```
AT+CSCS="GSM" // change character set to GSM
AT+CUSD=1,"*111#",15 // Issued balance check ussd code
```

It now works fine.

The default encoding was UCS2, I'd appreciate if someone can share how to convert ussd codes to UCS2 encoding in putty.

Comment: Not sure how you modem deals with UCS2. But I have some other Sierra Wireless modems where you just convert the characters to hex and it works.

Comment: Very valuable information, thanks for providing this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried issuing request by AT+CUSD=1,"*111#" ? (without last parameter)
AT cmmands sometimes differ due to manufacturer implementation.

Comment: Yes, causes no difference. The blank command gets accepted as well without the last parameter ... so I guess it doen't make a difference in my setup.

Comment: @dfgg Please use comments to ask an user clarification on is question.